# Is it possible to evoke Chrome Frame in IE ActiveX control

Tags: internet-explorer, activex, google-chrome-frame

I have an application which uses embedded IE as a viewer. However IE lacks needed feature available in Google Chrome Frame (GCF), but unfortunately GCF does not work in IE ActiveX control, but only in IE application.

As GCF is ActiveX object, is it possible to write simple vbscript/jscript in HTML document (intended for viewing) that will load GCF and render the contents inside embedded IE?

Comment: See this: http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/chrome_frame/host.html

Comment: Thanks, but I already tried that prior asking. This is what I get if I load that html page in both IE ActiveX object and IE application: http://i.imgur.com/3NAWV.png BTW if it's not so obvious by the visual style, it's IE 8.0 on Windows XP SP3

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ActiveX for Chrome` Extension.

1. Enter "gcf:about:version" at the location bar.
2. Right click to popup the right menu.
3. Click Inspect Element, You will get a window.
4. Click the system icon of the window, select the open New Window Item.
5. Install the Extension into GCF.

Have fun!